# Application of Schwarz lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic. I now want to show that $$|f'(z)| \leq \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$.

I think it has to do with the Schwarz lemma, but in that lemma there's an extra condition that $f(0) = 0$. Or does it have to do with the fact that we can write any conformal map (bijective and holomorphic) of $\mathbb{D}$ as $$e^{i\theta}\frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a}z}?$$ Where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{D}$.

Any hints are welcome!

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ My sketch goes as follows: If we can define a new automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ (call it $g$) from $f$ where it holds that $g(0) =0$ then by Schwarz's Lemma we have that $$|g(z)| \leq |z| \Rightarrow 1-|g(z)|^2 \geq 1-|z|^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1-|g(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2} \geq 1.$$ If we can somehow find that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$ then we have completed the proof.

But does this last bit hold? I can't seem to find a satisfactory explanation for why that should hold...

Comment: Check out schwarz pick lemma

Comment: f is any holomorphic function on $\mathbb D$. It need not be injective or surjective or bijective.